# Copy hashtable to another hashtable using c++

Tags: c++, hashtable

I am starting with c++ and need to know, what should be the approach to copy one hashtable to another hashtable in C++?

We can easily do this in java using: `HashMap copyOfOriginal=new HashMap(original);`

But what about C++? How should I go about it?

**UPDATE**

Well, I am doing it at a very basic level,perhaps the java example was a wrong one to give. This is what I am trying to implement using C++:

I have this hash array and each element of the array is the head of a linked list. Which has it's individual nodes (data and next pointer).

And now, I need to copy the complete hash array and the linked list each node is pointing to.

Comment: Given that you're describing the internals of your hashmap, it sounds like a custom implementation. Either post its code or convert to a common implementation such as SGI `hash_map` or TR1 `unordered_map`. (Both should be available in GCC and MSVC.) All we can tell is that your implementation is missing an important feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, what hash table implementation are you using? There is no hash table provided by the current version of ISO C++. That said, if your hash table class does not make `operator=` and its copy constructor private, then it would be a reasonable assumption that both will behave as expected. If not, I'd consider it a bug.

As an aside [std::unordered_map](http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/C%2B%2B0xFAQ.html#std-unordered) is being added in ISO C++ 2010, but ISO C++ 1998 and ISO C++ 1998 with the 2003 amendments do not have a hash map container. Microsoft provided a non-standard "std::hash_map", which they should never have placed in the "std::" namespace. They have since moved it to "stdext::" (which is good news). Some other vendors copied MSFT to make their compilers compatible.

If you are anxious to use a hash table implementation right away, then use [boost::unordered_map](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/doc/html/boost/unordered_map.html) from the [Boost C++ Libraries](http://www.boost.org/). The Boost C++ Libraries are open source, very popular, and high quality.

**EDIT**
Based on your updated question, you will need to create your own copy constructor, a swap function, and an implementation of operator= in order to do this. Usually operator= is trivial once you have swap and a copy constructor in place. Here is a sketch of how you would do this:

```
template<typename T>
HashTable<T>::HashTable(const HashTable<T>& o)
{
   // pseudo code:
   //     initialize as in HashTable<T>::HashTable()
   //     for each key/value pair in o:
   //        insert that key/value pair into this instance
   //
   // NOTE:
   //     if your hash table is sized so that the number of
   //     elements is a prime number, you can do better
   //     than the pseudo-code given above, but otherwise
   //     copying element by element is the way to go.
   //

   // BEGIN YOUR CODE
   // ...
   // END YOUR CODE
}

template<typename T> HashTable<T>&
HashTable<T>::swap(HashTable<T>& o)
{
     // Swap data pointers
     T* datatmp = _data;
     _data = o._data;
     o._data = datatmp;

     // Swap capacity
     size_t captmp = _capacity;
     _capacity = o._capacity;
     o._capacity = captmp;

     // Swap other info
     // ...

     // Report self
     return *this;
}
```

```
template<typename T> HashTable<T>&
HashTable<T>::operator=(const HashTable<T>& o)
{
     HashTable<T> cpy(o);
     return swap(cpy);
}
```

You will have to take the signatures from the above and add them to your declaration. I should also point out that one reason that `operator=` tends to be implemented in terms of swap is that, not only is it very simple to do and having a swap function makes your code very fast when that operation is needed, but also for the purposes of exception safety... your swap should pretty much never fail, but copy construction might... so if the copy construction throws an exception, you haven't thrown the object's state to hell.

Comment: To be fair, the reason it was there was from Dinkumware's shipment of the STL, which includes hash_map, because it existed in the original STL from SGI.

Answer (score 2):

Whichever hashmap you're using, I'm sure it has a copy-constructor and possibly `operator=`.

```
hashmap_type newMap = oldMap; // copies
```

And that's it. C++ has no standard hash map, though.

Comment: @stefanB, no, you're wrong. std::unordered_map is being added in C++0x, but there is no hash map class in ISO C++ 1998 (w/2003 ammendments).

Comment: The STL is not C++.  C++ has no standard hash map, although `std::unordered_map` will fill that void once C++0x is finalized.

Comment: @Dennis, the STL is a part of the C++ language... the standard library is just as much a part of C++ as is the language syntax and semantics, and is adopted by the same standardization process.

Comment: @Michael Aaron Safyan: SGI's original STL is _NOT_ part of the C++ language. SGI's original STL contains hash_map. The standard does not.

Comment: @Billy, SGI's implementation of STL is not "the STL". The STL is whatever is defined to be the STL by the ISO C++ standards committee. Maybe you're confusing me with stefanB?

Comment: The C++ standard makes no reference to any standard template library.  It defines a standard library.  To say "The STL" is a part of the C++ language is simply wrong.  --Although yes, I did get you and stefanB confused :-)

Comment: sgi has `operator=` sgi.com/tech/stl/hash_map.html, microsoft does not list it msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/… (but that might be just microsoft way of doing things ...) EDIT: I was talking about `operator=` not the `hash_map` support sorry for the confusion

Comment: @GMan Are you losing your grip :-) There's no operator=() in the code in your answer!

Answer (score 2):

In C++ you would use either the copy constructor or simple assignment (with values) to perform this.

For example

```
std::map<int,string> map1 = CreateTheMap();
std::map<int,string> map2 = map1; 
std::map<int,string> map3(map1);
```

Comment: std::map is not a hash map, though.

Comment: Okay, replace with `unordered_map`.

Comment: @Michael, this appears to be more of a general question. I don't think the OP was looking for an example that included a C++ type that matches Java semantics exactly

Comment: @JaredPar: There is no C++ type that matches Java semantics exactly. Any question asking for "Type X which matches language semantics of language Y in language Z" almost always results in "It does not exist". Different languages have different idioms. One should use idioms appropriate to that language.

Comment: @Billy, while that may be true, you aren't going to get the same syntax or method names, it is reasonable to expect a container with similar behavior and the same asymptotic complexity. The std::map has a very different runtime complexity than boost::unordered_map (and, very soon, std::unordered_map) and Java's HashMap. It is very reasonable to want an O(1) insertion and O(1) lookup.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid, somehow, that you are using a custom `HashMap` class, since you speak about its implementation details.

In C++, when it comes to copying a class, there is a special purpose `Copy Constructor`, which syntax looks like:

```
class Foo
{
public:
  Foo(); // regular constructor

  Foo(const Foo& rhs); // copy constructor
};
```

It can be invoked with either syntax:

```
Foo copy(original);
Foo copy2 = original;
```

Now, if you `HashMap` does not provide a copy constructor, my first suggestion is to switch to an existing implementation, like `boost::unordered_map` or if available `std::hash_map`, `std::tr1::hash_map` or `std::tr1::unordered_map`. The reasons there are so may `std::` possibilities is that many STL features a `hash_map` long before it was standardized. `unordered_map` is here to stay though, and the boost one too.

If you can't switch you are bound to implement the copy operation somehow.